# The method or operation is not implemented while invoking workflow Activity in C#

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4, invoke

I have a C# application which invokes a workflow activity

`WorkflowInvoker.Invoke(new WorkflowClassName(),...);`

The workflow is an xaml document which defines this class name.  It is in the same namespace as the code that is invoking it.  I am trying to write an integration test for this code, so I have a new project which references this project.  I have a test class in the new project, which creates the class which invokes the Workflow activity.  It compiles fine, but then I get the error :

```
   Exception System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented. 
at System.Activities.WorkflowApplication.Invoke(Activity activity, IDictionary`2 inputs, WorkflowInstanceExtensionManager extensions, TimeSpan timeout)
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: The method you are calling is not implemented. Are you instantiating a concrete class and storing it in a base or abstract class variable?

Comment: The callstack tells you what method isn't implemented.  Why isn't it implemented?  Implement it.